# Problem related to D'Alemberts's solution to wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was looking at the problem and failed to understand the last  few lines:

[image]

Everything looks fine until I came across the last few lines. I want to know how $u(x,1),\,\,\,u(x,2)$ are evaluated. Can someone explains in details.  Thanks and regards to all.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is given by
$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{6}\int_{x-3t}^{x+3t}G(s) \textrm{d} s.$$
So
$$u(x,1) = \frac{1}{6}\int_{x-3}^{x+3}G(s) \textrm{d} s. $$

Recall that $G(s)$ is piecewise defined to be $1$ if $|s| \leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise.

If $x > 4$ then $x - 3 > 1$ and so in the integral $s > 1$ and $G(s) = 0$. Thus $u(x,1) = 0$ for $x > 4$.

Similarly, if $x< -4$ then $u(x,1) = 0$.

What if $x$ lies between $-4$ and $4$? Well, then the function $G(s)$ is not zero over the entire range of integration and there is some contribution, so $u(x,1)$ is non-zero. Try to do these integrals yourself and recover the given solution.

I will add additional details in about an hour if you are still stuck. For now, think about the following picture:

[image]

Consider the case when $-1 < x - 3 \leq 1$, equivalently $2 < x \leq 4$ (see the picture above). Then the integral is just equal to the area of the shaded rectangle. The height of the rectangle is $1$, and the base of the rectangle is $1 - (x-3)$.

$$u(x,1) = \frac{1}{6}\int_{x-3}^{x+3}G(s) \textrm{d} s = \frac{1}{6}(1)(1-(x-3)) = \frac{4 - x}{6}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation. I was thinking about it.But still I do not understand few steps. When $-4<x \le -2 $, That is x lies in the region where $|x|>1.$so in that case, $G(x)=0.$ Can you explain the first step in evaluating $u(x,1)$ when  $-4<x \le -2$.

Comment: If $-4 < x \leq -2$ then $-1 < x + 3 \leq 1$, i.e. the right hand end point of the region of integration lies inside the non-zero part of $G(s)$...

Comment: Then we have to break the interval in between $(x-3,x+3)$ as the left hand end point lies in the region where $|x|>1.$ How will I partition that?

Comment: I've added more detail in my answer.

Comment: I also noticed that $x+3 >-1 \implies x+4 \ge 0.$ So if I take  $g(x)=1$ in $(0,x+4)$,then I get desired result.Is it that case?

Comment: Yes, that looks right.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details. I think I have to think about it for some more time. I will let you know if I am stuck again.